# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ProposalsRegistrationEndedEvent.watch is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle, events, ganache, truffle-contract

I was following an old Ethereum dapp tutorial to make a voting dapp. It uses truffle contract, web3js and ganache and when i access the pages via localhost i get the following error in the console: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ProposalsRegistrationStartedEvent.watch is not a function**

The code block in question is as follows:

```
SimpleVoting.deployed()
        .then(instance => instance.ProposalsRegistrationStartedEvent())
        .then(proposalsRegistrationStartedEventSubscription => {
            ProposalsRegistrationStartedEvent = proposalsRegistrationStartedEventSubscription;  

            ProposalsRegistrationStartedEvent.watch(function(error, result) {
              if (!error)
                $("#proposalsRegistrationMessage").html('The proposals registration session has started');
              else
                console.log(error);
            });           
        });
```

And the code for the solidity event is simply:

```
event ProposalsRegistrationStartedEvent ();
```

Comment: Hey there, did you try to console log and see what is in `ProposalsRegistrationStartedEvent`?

The error indicates that `ProposalsRegistrationStartedEvent.watch` might not be a valid executable function

Comment: @YosephKurniaSoenggoro Hi, i did console.log(ProposalsRegistrationStartedEvent) and it shows, in the console, an EventEmitter but its fields are mostly empty/undefined.